# Extra Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Does anyone have a solution on how to integrate/activate a second gutenberg editor within WordPress?

For the moment the Gutenberg editor parses the_content().

What I would like to achieve is a header introduction text where the user can add its own blocks, apart from the default content.

Comment: By default, the gutenberg editor lets you create your own blocks. It doesn't have sense the question.

Comment: I would change the structure of how you work, and use GB  blocks for everything. then you can fill up your page with blocks, and not use the title as a page title, but just as a backend name for the user as a reference. the actual title then is going to be a block. And that block can be anything you want.
You can also fix the entire pages blocks, so they can not be moved, if you like a static page for the user.

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no as such thing but WordPress is targetting it for future. The Gutenberg editor is the first phase of WordPress in which it embraces the modern JavaScript and there is phase 2 under development. Phase 1 only targetted the content part of the WordPress while phase 2 targets each and every thing like header, menu's, widgets etc. The final result of phase 2 is to edit each section with Gutenberg like behavior.

Phase 2: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/12/08/gutenberg-phase-2/

It means for now you are left with custom plugin development or use plugins like ACF.